# Javascript table export to excel utf8

Tags: javascript, excel, utf-8, html-table, export-to-excel

I need some function that export my html table as excel file. The following codes do this but it saves the table in wrong charset. I need to make it UTF-8.

Here is my code:

```
function exceller() { //UI
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64; charset=UTF-8,',
        template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64 = function (s) {
            return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
        },
        format = function (s, c) {
            return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) {
                return c[p];
            });
        };
    table = document.getElementById("pztable");
    $('#toExcel').html($(table).html());
    $('#toExcel').find("thead > tr > th:last-child").remove();
    $('#toExcel').find("tbody > tr > td:last-child").remove();
    var toExcel = $('#toExcel').html();
    var ctx = {
        worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
        table: toExcel
    };
    $('#toExcel').remove();
    window.open(uri + base64(format(template, ctx)));
}
```

Note: my real table's id is "pztable" but I am deleting the last column of it because I don't want to export that column. so I'm creating a table with id="toExcel" and then I am exporting that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved The problem. 
Here is the last version of the code is.

```
function exceller() { //UI
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    table = document.getElementById("pztable");
    $('#toExcel').html($(table).html());
    $('#toExcel').find("thead > tr > th:last-child").remove();
    $('#toExcel').find("tbody > tr > td:last-child").remove();
    var toExcel = $('#toExcel').html();
    var ctx = {
        worksheet: name || '',
        table: toExcel
    };
    $('#toExcel').remove();
    window.open(uri + base64(format(template, ctx)));
}
```